# Removing ArraList Elements in a Method

Tags: java, arraylist

[EDIT]Fairly new to the site so editted to try to clarify the problem.

I am working on a project where I have a method in which one of the parameters is an array.

Example:

```
public class Match

public void playMatch(int teamA, int teamB, ArrayList<String> groups)
Random scoreA = new Random();
int score1 = scoreA.nextInt(5) + 0;
int score2 = scoreA.nextInt(5) + 0;
System.out.println("Qtr 1: " + score1 + "   " + score2);

if (score1 > score2){
    System.out.println(groups.get(teamA) + " win " + score1 + " to +   
    score2 + " " + teams.get(teamB) + " eliminated.");
            teams.remove(teamB);
}
else if (score2 > score1){
    System.out.println(groups.get(teamB) + " win " + score2 + " to " +  
    score11 + " " + teams.get(teamA) + " eliminated.");
            teams.remove(teamA);}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Match game1 = new Match();
ArrayList<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList("team1", "team2", "team3"));
System.out.println("Round 1");
game1.playMatch(0, 1, groups);
```

The problem is that when I remove the element in my Matches method it does not remove it from the ArrayList in my main method. This is an issue because I want to be able to then do:

`game2.playMatch(0, 1, groups)`

Where 1 = team3 instead of team 2.

How can I make it so that when I remove an element from the Array in my Matches method it actually will remove that element from the Array in my main method? Is this even possible? I would prefer to have something that fits into my code if it is possible and i don't want to have to implement another method if I don't have to as there is actually a lot more than this but this gives the jist of what I want to have happen.

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: Note that an array and an arraylist are two different things.

Comment: `exampleArray.remove(1);` should probably be `exampleArray.remove(elem1);`

Comment: I apologize for the poor question formatting, I am fairly new to the site. I hope that this is clearer.

Comment: You passed in groups, but you're modifying something called teams.  That's your problem.

Comment: This was an error on my part, teams = groups, it is changed now. I had to retype my code so it was easier to present here as there is a lot more than this but this issue is all that is standing in the way of it working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored what you gave and the below works on my end and seems to do what you're asking.  Fixed a bunch of syntax errors, and formatting stuff.  Looks like you're not accounting for ties where score1 == score2.  Please try the below code, taking note of the print outs of the list I added to your main method before and after modification, and see if it helps

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyMatch {

    public void playMatch(int teamA, int teamB, List<String> groups) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int score1 = rand.nextInt(5) + 0;
        int score2 = rand.nextInt(5) + 0;
        System.out.println("Qtr 1: " + score1 + "   " + score2);

        if (score1 > score2){
            System.out.println(groups.get(teamA) + " win " + score1 + " to " +   
            score2 + " " + groups.get(teamB) + " eliminated.");
            groups.remove(teamB);
        } else if (score2 > score1){
            System.out.println(groups.get(teamB) + " win " + score2 + " to " +  
            score1 + " " + groups.get(teamA) + " eliminated.");
            groups.remove(teamA);
        } else if (score1 == score2) {
            System.out.println(groups.get(teamA) + " tie " + score1 + " to " +
            groups.get(teamB) + " " + score2 + " no team was eliminated.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyMatch game1 = new MyMatch();
        List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("team1","team2", "team3"));
        System.out.println("Round 1");
        System.out.println("BEFORE: " + groups);
        game1.playMatch(0, 1, groups);
        System.out.println("AFTER: " + groups);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, why does this work just switching syntax from ArrayList to List though? I mean, that is literally all I did via this answer and it works where the ArrayList did not.

Comment: That isn't why it works now.  That's another long discussion on polymorphism that is too long for this post. Here's a good link.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm.  Anyway,  there were a lot of syntax errors in your code (i.e. missing curly braces, incorrectly named variables like score11 and teams, a missing quote in your first print stmt, etc), not to mention formatting made it hard to read.  Are you using an IDE like eclipse?  If so, it would catch the compilation errors in your code.  Other than that your code was fine!

Comment: ArrayList is-a List.  Java (the JVM) figures out which implementation of List it is at runtime (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc...).  If you use List<T> as your parameter type in your methods instead of ArrayList<T>, that is a best practice, as it gives your code the flexibility to accept different implementations of List to make your code more scalable and reusable later on.  You can also instantiate your List with List rather than ArrayList as your declared type (left hand side of the object assignment). Make sense?

Comment: Your code didn't account for ties.  I've modified my answer and added a 3rd else if handling ties.  That is likely the case where you're seeing the teams not removed.

Comment: Thank you for all of the assistance and I will take a look at the link you provided. When I was pulling my code out of my IDE to paste here I just forgot to grab the curly braces with it and as for the mis-stated variable and such that is probably because I was pulling code from multiple sections of my program and trying to rewrite it here so it made sense, the program is a few hundred lines right now and I didn't want to just throw it all up here and leave you all to sort through it. The curly braces  are in my code though but thanks for going the extra step to try and help me anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, you will pass three arguments to removeByIndex method: a (a given index), b (another given index) and arrayList (the container of the elements). Then, it will make a copy (clone) of the container, find the lowest index amongst a and b, remove the element at that index from the arrayList and return the modified copy.

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeByIndex(int a, int b, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

    ArrayList<String> clone = (ArrayList<String>) arrayList.clone();

    int minIndex = Math.min(a, b);

    clone.remove(minIndex);

    return clone;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> example = new ArrayList<String>();

    example.add("One");
    example.add("Two");
    example.add("Three");
    example.add("Four");
    example.add("Five");

    System.out.println(example);

    example = removeByIndex(1, 3, example);

    System.out.println(example);
}
```

Note that you must assign the return of the method to the container, otherwise it will not be modified.

Comment: I apologize for the poor question formatting, I am fairly new to the site. I hope that this is clearer.

Comment: @Marcelo Vinicius:  Hmm.... can you help me understand why you're cloning the arrayList?

Comment: Is cloning not a different thing from passing it into a method? I am doing it this way so that I can just call the method. If I have 50 teams I can just call the method 50 times after initializing the ArrayList and filling it with teams as opposed to writing hundreds of lines of code. Is this what you are asking?